# Python - How do I find partial string occurrence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

I am search through a list of lists like this ...

```
srchList = [ ['Gloucestershire', 'Tewkesbury', '324225'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Tirley', '353925'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Westbury Court Garden', '354153'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Westonbirt', '354163'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Winchcombe', '354244'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Withington, '354270'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Woodchester Park (Nt)', '354288'], ['Gloucestershire', 'Wotton', '354320'], ['Greater London', 'Tennis Club Wimbledon', '324383'], ['Greater London', 'Arsenal F.C.', '350150'], ['Greater London', 'Barking', '324164'], ['Greater London', 'Barnet', '324151'], 
['Greater London', 'Beckton', '350286'], ['Greater London', 'Bexley', '350413'] ]
```

In order to select those in London, I have to enter "Greater London"

I have evaded problems with capitalisation with `.upper()` but how can I get a hit
if I just enter a partial string, such as `"london"` or `"Gloucester"` ?

This is my current code ...

```
result = [region for region in srchList if region[0].upper() == search_item.upper()]
if result == []:
    print("Search item not found")
else:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead (it checks to see if what you search for is anywhere in any of the regions in the list using the `in` operator)

```
result = [region for region in srchList if search_item.upper() in region[0].upper()]
if result == []:
    print("Search item not found")
else:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Brilliant !!! That works well.

Comment: @Dave if it solves your problem please don't forget to accept it by hitting the check mark